# Transforming a long block of code into a function (in Python)

Tags: python, pandas, function, numpy

I have a long block of code that essentially reads in a file, converts a column to datetime, filters out some data, performs a groupby action and ***ultimately produces a table that displays a highlighted conditional data***. ***I would like these actions to be called under one function***. Is this possible?

**Here is a small sample of the data:**

```
Size        Date        POD

0.027289    11/1/2020   IA1
0.013563    11/1/2020   IA1
0.058498    11/1/2020   IA1
0.281953    11/1/2020   IA1
0.479725    11/1/2020   IA1
0.007358    11/1/2020   IA1
0.075818    11/1/2020   IA1
0.069744    11/1/2020   IA1
0.029844    11/1/2020   IA1
0.38383     11/1/2020   IA2
0.3451      11/1/2020   IA2
0.034024    11/1/2020   IA2
0.292939    11/1/2020   IA2
0.208562    11/1/2020   IA2
0.013108    11/1/2020   IA2
0.047918    11/1/2020   FA1
0.087911    11/1/2020   FA1
0.014931    11/1/2020   FA1
1.921362    11/1/2020   FA1
0.014619    11/1/2020   FA1
0.069832    11/1/2020   FA1
1.86548     11/1/2020   FA1
2.908355    11/1/2020   FA1
1.841789    11/1/2020   FA1
1.547088    11/1/2020   FA1
1.831961    11/1/2020   FA1
0.308858    7/1/2019    GA1
0.002721    7/1/2019    GA1
0.762241    7/1/2019    GA1
0.029349    7/1/2019    GA1
1.594415    7/1/2019    GA1
0.205912    7/1/2019    GA1
0.16714     7/1/2019    GA1
```

**Desired output:**

***To be able to call one function that would perform all of the actions within it***

job("file.csv")

**This is what I am doing:**

```
def job(file):  #read in the file using the function 
    
    df = pd.read_csv(file)  
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])   
    df1 = df.loc[df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='M'),'Size'])
         .Date.transform('min') == df['Date']
      ]
    df2 = df1.loc[df1.Date.dt.day==1]
    df3 = df2[~df2.POD.str.contains('IA1')]
    df4 = df3[~df3.POD.str.contains('IA2')]
    df5 = df4.groupby(['POD','Date'], as_index=False).sum() 
    df6 = df5.sort_values(["POD", "Date", "Size"])
    gp_obj = df6.groupby("POD")
    
    df6["Start_Date"] = gp_obj["Date"].shift()
    df6["Diff"] = gp_obj["Size"].diff()
    df6["Percent"] = df6["Diff"] / df6["Size"].shift() * 100

    df6.rename(columns={"Date": "End_Date"}, inplace=True)
    df6 = df6[["POD", "Start_Date", "End_Date", "Diff", "Percent"]][~df6["Diff"].isna()]
    
    df6['Date']= df6.apply(lambda x: x['Start_Date'].strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
    + ' '+'to'+ ' '+x['End_Date'].strftime('%m-%d-%Y'),1)
    
    
    condition=[(df6.POD.eq('FA1')&df6.Percent.gt(6))|(df6.POD.eq('GA1')&df6.Percent.gt(20))
    ,(df6.POD.eq('FA1')&df6.Percent.lt(1))|(df6.POD.eq('GA1')&df6.Percent.lt(6))]
    
        
    choice=['Too High','Too Low']   
    df6['result']=np.select(condition, choice, 'ok')
    
         def highlight(val):                               

             if 'Too High' in str(val):                     
                    color='lightpink'
            elif 'Too Low' in str(val):
                   color='lightgreen'                       
            else:
                   color=''                                  
        return f'background-color: {color}'           

        df.style.applymap(highlight)   
        
        return
```

I would like to simply call the function by placing the file I wish to transform inside of it:

```
job('file.csv')
```

**updated**

[image]

*********However, when I 'call' the function, by typing:***

**job('file.csv')**, I do not see any output, all I see is:

**<function **main**.job(file)>.*****

Any suggestion is appreciated***

Comment: The function never uses the `file` argument.

Comment: ok let me update the post, thank you

Comment: You just need to start the function with `df = pd.read_csv(file)`

Comment: inside of the function? ok this is what I initially had, but was not sure - I thought when you call the function, this is when you place that filename inside (as the parameter?)

Comment: Try putting df=pd.read_csv(file) in the beginning of your function then keep using it. It seems like you may have hard coded it earlier.

Comment: @Lynnette You call a function with arguments, and then inside the function the parameter variable contains the argument value.

Comment: So you can call `job("file1.csv")` and then `job("file2.csv")`, and `file` will contain whichever filename was used for that call. This is programming 101.

Comment: Oh I see @barmar ok I will try this. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Yes I am always learning @Barmar I know this part, this is why I have this inside of my post:  job(file.csv)

Comment: You need quotes around the filename in the argument.

Comment: ok thank you for the suggestion. Yes I am trying this now. @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few observations:

1.

```
def highlight(val):                               

    if 'Too High' in str(val):                     
        color='lightpink'
    elif 'Too Low' in str(val):
        color='lightgreen'                       
    else:
         color=''                                  
    return f'background-color: {color}'
```

is a separate function, take it outside completely, it doesn't need to be nested. Put it above the job function.

2. your main function `job` doesn't return anything.
   Assuming your logic inside is correct, your final output
   will be df6. (or df6 with highlighting, see below)

Your function has to return a DataFrame for you to see a DataFrame as output.

eg: `return df6`

3. i'm not fully sure if the highlight map function works, but you applying it to `df`, and not `df6`?  By the logic
   of script, shouldn't it be  `df6.style.applymap(highlight)`?

If you sure highlight function works, then apply it on df6 before return,
i.e.

`return df6.style.applymap(highlight)`

Side question:  what is the reason for creating so many versions of df (df1,df2...)?  You don't seem to be calling previously stored versions?
I think you can do most if not all of the trasformations while keeping just one df.

eg: instead of

```
df1 = df.loc[df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='M'),'Size'])
         .Date.transform('min') == df['Date']]
```

you can just use

```
df = df.loc[df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='M'),'Size'])
.Date.transform('min') == df['Date']]
```

**EDITED FOR FORMAT CLARITY:**

```
## define highlight function
def highlight(val):                               

            if 'Too High' in str(val):                     
                    color='lightpink'
            elif 'Too Low' in str(val):
                   color='lightgreen'                       
            else:
                   color=''                                  
        return f'background-color: {color}'

## define main function
def job(file):  #read in the file using the function 
    
    df = pd.read_csv(file)  
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])   
    df1 = df.loc[df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='M'),'Size'])
         .Date.transform('min') == df['Date']
      ]
    df2 = df1.loc[df1.Date.dt.day==1]
    df3 = df2[~df2.POD.str.contains('IA1')]
    df4 = df3[~df3.POD.str.contains('IA2')]
    df5 = df4.groupby(['POD','Date'], as_index=False).sum() 
    df6 = df5.sort_values(["POD", "Date", "Size"])
    gp_obj = df6.groupby("POD")
    
    df6["Start_Date"] = gp_obj["Date"].shift()
    df6["Diff"] = gp_obj["Size"].diff()
    df6["Percent"] = df6["Diff"] / df6["Size"].shift() * 100

    df6.rename(columns={"Date": "End_Date"}, inplace=True)
    df6 = df6[["POD", "Start_Date", "End_Date", "Diff", "Percent"]][~df6["Diff"].isna()]
    
    df6['Date']= df6.apply(lambda x: x['Start_Date'].strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
    + ' '+'to'+ ' '+x['End_Date'].strftime('%m-%d-%Y'),1)
    
    
    condition=[(df6.POD.eq('FA1')&df6.Percent.gt(6))|(df6.POD.eq('GA1')&df6.Percent.gt(20))
    ,(df6.POD.eq('FA1')&df6.Percent.lt(1))|(df6.POD.eq('GA1')&df6.Percent.lt(6))]
    
        
    choice=['Too High','Too Low']   
    df6['result']=np.select(condition, choice, 'ok')
              
    ##apply higlights to latest dataframe (change df to df6?) and return it     
    ### to debug without highlights, replace df6.style.applymap(highlight) below with just df6

    return df6.style.applymap(highlight) 


### print your function's output:
print(job('file_name.csv'))

### or save output to some dataframe you want to further inspect
df_check = job('file_name.csv')
print(df_check)
```

In order to debug, separate debugging 'highlights' from 'job'.  First make sure 'job' gives you data output you want.  To do so change`return df6.style.applymap(highlight)` to `return df6`. That will give you output without highlights.  Then switch back to output with highlights.

Comment: Ok thank you - this is very helpful- I’ll try your suggestions and see if this works

Comment: Could I include the highlight function in this main function? The main function is step 1 and whatever output is from step 1 would be fed into the 2nd function (highlight function) thanks for your suggestion

Comment: You can use the function in your main one.  Just declare it separately.  It makes code easier to use and maintain.

Comment: Thank you- so I would have to ‘call’ them separately too though right? job(‘file.csv’) and then highlight(df6) ?

Comment: You can call the highlight function from inside the job funtion.  I.e. it is just another step in your processing, that you apply before returning result.  Thats why you need to declare it before job funtion, so it exists when job funtion looks for it.   Once your two functions are created, provided they work, you'll just call job('csv') to get output.  Most important thing is make sure your main function returns a dataframe!

Comment: Ok when you say ‘call the highlight function from inside the job function’ do you mean: after declaring highlight function outside of the job function, I’d have to create job function and give it two parameters? i.e def job(file, highlight) ? —- then when I’d like to call it, I can just: job(‘file.csv’)

Comment: If you take a look at the code that you shared, highlight function is a self contained block from declaration to return, that doesn't depend on any values from the main function.  Therefore it can be taken outside of 'job' without any affect on job.  Now you are calling it right after with `df.style.applymap(highlight)` inside the function.  I don't see any `val` been passed.  i'm assuming it's special setup for style function (i don't use it, so i'm not sure).  But if that's all you need now,that's all you need with the function declared outside.

Comment: i edited the answer to show suggested placement of blocks.

Comment: I will try this in the morning- thank you for your helpful input

Comment: Thank you @yulGM - the entire program worked. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I don't have that much experience working with files, but I'd suggest to state the file argument as a variable inside the function, since all the manipulation seems to be present in the function, but the file is never present. Like `file = 'address of the file'`. Sorta like that. You can maybe append or create another file and return the manipulated data.

Comment: This answer is hard to understand. Could you show the actual code changes you're suggesting?

Comment: Oh, I hope I could atm. But anyway, it seems that a proper solution has been proposed!